# Elastic APM : cpu usage when running application.jar in local system

Tags: java, opentracing, elastic-apm

I am running a sample application jar on local system using elasticAPM agent.
Elastic APM show 2 different cpu stats (system/process).

Metrics explanation on official site says the same thing for both stats
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/server/current/exported-fields-system.html

Please explain, Is the "system cpu stats" is of my system even when the agent is connected to application.jar only using java command? If so, how can I check on elastic apm what else on my system in consuming cpu since only application is running during the load test.

java -javaagent:<agent.jar> -jar <app.jar>

The CPU usage shown below
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metrics shown in Kibana are sent by the APM agent that like you said has limited access to your environment. It basically says anything that is collected by the JVM running your JAR.

If you want to get further visibility into the CPU details of your local environment then you must augment your setup using [Elastic MetricBeats](https://www.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat) that ships O.S level details about your machine that sees beyond what the JVM can see.

In the presentation below I show how to configure logs, metrics, and APM altogether.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXbg9pZCjpk

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, so the system cpu which elastic apm displays is of JVM and the process cpu if for application running within?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Process CPU is the usage of CPU from the JVM perspective only.